# Token Authentication with django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

[This is output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pozL.png)I am trying to fetch data from the api endpoint using HTTPIE, following is the command,

```
http http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/ 'Authorization: Token c9a5b630b1887efdd3ca2db82aae9cec2c44257e'
```

I generated the token and appended it to the api endpoint, i used curl to fetch data too, but it shows similar error.

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated


class HelloView(APIView):
   permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

   def get(self,request):
     content = {'message': 'Hello'}
     return Response(content)
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'core',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
   'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
       'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
       'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
   ],
}
```

**Output**

```
usage: http [--json] [--form] [--pretty {all,colors,format,none}]
            [--style STYLE] [--print WHAT] [--headers] [--body] [--verbose]
            [--all] [--history-print WHAT] [--stream] [--output FILE]
            [--download] [--continue]
            [--session SESSION_NAME_OR_PATH | --session-read-only SESSION_NAME_OR_PATH]
            [--auth USER[:PASS]] [--auth-type {basic,digest}]
            [--proxy PROTOCOL:PROXY_URL] [--follow]
            [--max-redirects MAX_REDIRECTS] [--timeout SECONDS]
            [--check-status] [--verify VERIFY]
            [--ssl {ssl2.3,ssl3,tls1,tls1.1,tls1.2}] [--cert CERT]
            [--cert-key CERT_KEY] [--ignore-stdin] [--help] [--version]
            [--traceback] [--default-scheme DEFAULT_SCHEME] [--debug]
            [METHOD] URL [REQUEST_ITEM [REQUEST_ITEM ...]]
http: error: argument REQUEST_ITEM: "Token" is not a valid value
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your httpie command. What shell are you using to run the command? Bash?

Comment: I am executing on windows cmd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple as is as follows . Use double quotes in the place of single quotes contrary to what the [DRF Documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/)  says

For curl use the command below

```
curl -H "Authorization: Token c9a5b630b1887efdd3ca2db82aae9cec2c44257e" http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/
```

For HTTPie  use

```
http GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/ "Authorization: Token c9a5b630b1887efdd3ca2db82aae9cec2c44257e"
```

Note that Double quotes are used contrary to single quotes in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use curl or even postman to make the request and see if it works,

```
curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/ -H "Authorization: Token Your generated token here"
```

Or using postman, pass your token on the request header like this:

[image]

Don't forget to generate a token using the command

```
python manage.py drf_create_token YOURUSER
```

Comment: this is what i am getting: curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/ -H 'Authorization: Token c9a5b630b1887efdd3ca2db82aae9cec2c44257e'
{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Token
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: c9a5b630b1887efdd3ca2db82aae9cec2c44257e'

Comment: try with double quotes "" instead of ''

Comment: Try what Mr-Programs said.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Windows, you should use double quotes to contain the `Authorization` header. Windows (specifically cmd.exe) doesn't recognize the single quotes and treats each part of the header as a separate argument.

So change to:

```
http http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/ "Authorization: Token c9a5b630b1887efdd3ca2db82aae9cec2c44257e"
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you settled headers for http call ?

```
--headers
```

It's an example from API doc:

```
curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/example/ -H 'Authorization: Token 9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem itself resolved when I switched cmd to windows 10. bash.

Answer (score 0):

Double vs single quotes in curl command was the fix for me. I was using single and getting auth problems. Double quotes worked.